# Regular Expression CSV Email

Tags: asp.net, regex, csv

I need help with a regular expression for .net validation. I need to validate a CSV list of emails. We currently use: `[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2}` to validate emails. I also have `[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*` to validate numeric CSV: 10 or 1,3,5 etc.

Combining the two into `[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2}+(,[\w\.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,})*(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}){1,2}+)` results into a Nested quantifier +. I can't figure out a suitable regex that validates emails and the csv list.

Splitting and validating individually is not an easy option.

Comment: What is your question then? Why not use the [`MailAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailaddress.aspx) class to verify email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

Go crazy and use [RFC 2822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#section-3.4.1) syntax »

```
^(?:(?:[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*|"(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21\x23-\x5b\x5d-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])*")@(?:(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?|\[(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?|[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9]:(?:[\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x21-\x5a\x53-\x7f]|\\[\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x7f])+)\])(?:,(?=.))?)+$
```

[image]